# TeamCity doesn't see geckodriver path

Tags: teamcity, robotframework, geckodriver

I got my set of robot framework tests, that works correctly on my localhost.

The geckodriver is located in project folder as

> Project_name/webdrivers/geckodriver.exe

Then I have this keyword set as Test Setup:

```
Set Environment Variable  webdriver.gecko.driver  Project_name/webdrivers/geckodriver.exe
```

This however doesn't work when run tests via Team City, and I got this message:

> WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in
> PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easily solved by a google search for "add program to path"

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver`

---

You can expand the path for a build agent by adding a build parameter named "env.PATH" with the following value on Mac OS and Linux.

```
%env.PATH%:/my/path
```

On Windows use ";" instead of ":" as the path delimiter.

You can also add the following to conf/buildAgent.properties in your build agent installation directory.

```
env.PATH=%env.PATH%:/my/path
```

Comment: TeamCity runs on WinServer2019